# WindowServer taking up much RAM; in fact, too much

Tags: memory, bug

For the past few months—and the past few months only—my 2020 M1 MacBook Air has been behaving weirdly. The thread WindowServer keeps taking up an appallingly large amount of my memory; indeed, it exceeds my total of 8GB and somehow takes ~50GB. This happens every while after I reboot, and a reboot fixes the problem—or just force quitting WindowServer: that is how I lived through the past few months. I've finally decided to fight this; not knowing how, I am seeking help on this renowned platform.

[image: the problem]

Answer (score 1):

WindowServer is a fundamental process: as the name suggests, it's the thing that manages every window on the screen. Force Quitting it may cause other issues.

The summary information at the bottom of the window suggests that your Mac isn't using 45Gb at all. So perhaps it's just an error in stating the value.
Are you observing any slow-downs, or other issues that might be a result of large memory usage?

The large size is a symptom of a problem, rather than a problem in itself. You need to find what is causing this runaway memory.

First, make sure that you're on the latest release of your OS version, and/or update to the latest version.

Secondly, take a look at the applications that you have running. Quit them all. Launch one at a time, and see if one of them seems to trigger the memory increase. Are you using Chrome....? ;-)

Comment: I am not using chrome; I have always stuck to safari despite having installed it. The problem it causes me is, after this happens, a window that says 'insufficient memory' pops up forcing me to quit applications—that's why I'm bothered. I am, however, not on the newest OS: I am on Monterey. I'll make sure I update.